# Is it possible to expose Kibana (for ElasticSearch) features to users of a web application?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, kibana-4

From some videos I have watched about the [ELK stack](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/elk-stack-devops-environment), I see that there is no authentication mechanism for Kibana.

I have yet to begin using it, and would like to know a few things beforehand:  In a re-design, we are planning to use ElasticSearch through a .Net connector/DAL.  Users never have direct access to the database.

I would like to offer some of the reporting features that Kibana has to the users of this new web portal/dashboard, where users can get reports only based on their own data.

Is it possible to integrate Kibana into an authentication-based web portal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can integrate Kibana into an authentication system and Kibana 4.2 is suppose to include basic authentication. But this wont give you authorization. You can achieve that by using NginX if you want.

You can also use ELK as a service from Logz.io which include authentication and role based access. I am sure there are other ELK providers out there as well.

(Disclaimer - I am the co-founder and VP product at Logz.io)